# Use Regex to accept a string as long as it contains alphabet

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I want to accept a string as long as it contains alphabetical letters, for example: `String testStr = "hello world 1. ?"`

I am currently using this: `testStr.matches("^[a-zA-Z\\s]+")`, but it won't accept strings that have characters outside of the alphabet.

So I am wondering how to use regex in this situation.

Comment: Do you mean it has to include *at least* one letter, but you don't care what else it accepts? It would help if you could give examples of what it's *meant* to accept and reject, along with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: that's right. I only care about letters in the string. As long as the string contains letter(s), I can accept it regardless of other characters.

Comment: Again, this should be in the question, which should explain it all clearly with examples and a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the string contains at least one `[a-z]`

```
(?i)^(?=.*[a-z]).*
```

Or without the i-caseless [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html): `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*` / Check only: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xH0qB0/1)